# Use user form input in JS

Tags: javascript, forms

could someone please explain how i get user input from a form to use in JS? ive tried numerous things and the alert just keeps saying {object undefined}? It must be something simple but i cant seem to find the answer anywhere!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href = "style.css" rel ="stylesheet" type = "text/css">
    <script src="script.js" type ="text/javascript" defer ></script>
      <title>Tip Calculator</title>
</head>
<body class = "body">
    <div class = "form-container">
        <h1 class = "heading">Tip Calculator</h1>
        <form class = "form" method="GET" action="">
            <label for = "bill-amount">How much is the Bill?</label><br>
            <input type = "number" placeholder="£0.00" name = "bill-amount" id="bill-amount" data-bill><br>
            <label for = "service">How was the Service?</label><br>
            <select name = "serivce" id = "service">
                <option value = "poor">Poor - 5%</option>
                <option value = "good">Good - 10%</option>
                <option value = "excellent">Excellent - 20%</option><br>
            </select><br>
            <label for = "people" name = "people">How many People are spliting the Tip?</label><br>
            <input type = "number" name = "people" id = "people"><br>
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit" class = "submit" id = "submit">
        </form>
        <div class = "output"> 
            <p> Tip amount: <span class = "bill-amount">£0</span></p>
            <p> Tip amount: <span class = "tip-amount">£0</span></p>
            <p> Tip Per Person: <span class = "tip-person-amount">£0</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
const bill = document.getElementById('bill-amount')
const submit = document.getElementById('submit')

submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(bill)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the value of the field by using .value as shown in the code below. The example below pulls the value from the specified selector bill-amount field after the forms is submitted which is presumably after its received input. As a side note, since you're likely going to be doing calculations with this number, remember you have to parse that string into a float. You can do that with .parseFloat.

```js
const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
const bill = document.getElementById('bill-amount');

submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(bill.value) //returns a string to parse use .parseFloat
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the id `bill-amount` to the input element not the label.
and then use something like:

`bill = document.querySelector("#bill-amount").innerText;`

this way the value that the user input will be stored in `bill`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `bill` in your example is a reference to the HTML element with the id `bill-amount`. It's not a value by itself. To extract the value from the HTML element, you can do the following: `bill.value`. I have created a working snippet below based upon your sample code.

```js
const bill = document.getElementById('bill-amount')
const submit = document.getElementById('submit')

submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(bill.value)
})
```

```html
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href = "style.css" rel ="stylesheet" type = "text/css">
    <script src="script.js" type ="text/javascript" defer ></script>
      <title>Tip Calculator</title>
</head>
<body class = "body">
    <div class = "form-container">
        <h1 class = "heading">Tip Calculator</h1>
        <form class = "form" method="GET" action="">
            <label for = "bill-amount">How much is the Bill?</label><br>
            <input type = "number" placeholder="£0.00" name = "bill-amount" id="bill-amount" data-bill><br>
            <label for = "service">How was the Service?</label><br>
            <select name = "serivce" id = "service">
                <option value = "poor">Poor - 5%</option>
                <option value = "good">Good - 10%</option>
                <option value = "excellent">Excellent - 20%</option><br>
            </select><br>
            <label for = "people" name = "people">How many People are spliting the Tip?</label><br>
            <input type = "number" name = "people" id = "people"><br>
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit" class = "submit" id = "submit">
        </form>
        <div class = "output"> 
            <p> Tip amount: <span class = "bill-amount">£0</span></p>
            <p> Tip amount: <span class = "tip-amount">£0</span></p>
            <p> Tip Per Person: <span class = "tip-person-amount">£0</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this has worked, thank you. Can i use this value as number as i will be doing some simple math and also display that number as a string or will the value need converting?

Comment: Glad I could be of help, it will be a number in this case so there is no need to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const bill = document.getElementById('bill-amount')
const submit = document.getElementById('submit')

const form = document.forms[0] // documentGetById, by className or querySelector
form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const form = e.target;
    console.log(form.elements)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href = "style.css" rel ="stylesheet" type = "text/css">
    <script src="script.js" type ="text/javascript" defer ></script>
      <title>Tip Calculator</title>
</head>
<body class = "body">
    <div class = "form-container">
        <h1 class = "heading">Tip Calculator</h1>
        <form class = "form" method="GET" action="">
            <label for = "bill-amount">How much is the Bill?</label><br>
            <input type = "number" placeholder="£0.00" name = "bill-amount" id="bill-amount" data-bill><br>
            <label for = "service">How was the Service?</label><br>
            <select name = "serivce" id = "service">
                <option value = "poor">Poor - 5%</option>
                <option value = "good">Good - 10%</option>
                <option value = "excellent">Excellent - 20%</option><br>
            </select><br>
            <label for = "people" name = "people">How many People are spliting the Tip?</label><br>
            <input type = "number" name = "people" id = "people"><br>
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit" class = "submit" id = "submit">
        </form>
        <div class = "output"> 
            <p> Tip amount: <span class = "bill-amount">£0</span></p>
            <p> Tip amount: <span class = "tip-amount">£0</span></p>
            <p> Tip Per Person: <span class = "tip-person-amount">£0</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```